# Why code give segmentation fault on inputs greater than 10?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I am building AVL tree. When I give input below than 10 it works fine. but when I give greater than 10 then codes break down and say segmentation faults and give wrong output. This is for my school assignment.

The input is this format;

```
D13 D60 D76 D12 A17 D98 A94 D70 D3 A23 A42 D45 A100 D50 A99 A22 A87 A4
A90 D88 A71 A20 D39 D83 A97 A56 D28 A9 D43 A19 D5 A11 A54 A73 D54 A9 A24 A58 D6 D80 A72 A47 A82 A12 A75 D77 D84 D86 A60 D64 D70 D70 A73 A71 A40 D94 D27 A63 D47 A42 A44 A27 A100 A6 D84 A19 D65 A75 A55 A63 A39 D99 A50 D98 A98 D100 D93 A91 A81 D59 D56 D29 D11 D45 D47 D55 D85 D7 D70 A13 A55 A25 D35 D65 A48 D55 A45 D29 A35 A15 IN
```

and output comes like:

```
4 6 9 12 13 15 17 19 20 22 23 24 25 27 35 39 40 42 44 45 48 50 58
60 63 71 72 73 75 81 82 87 90 91 97 98
```

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    /* First we are going to design structure for Nodes. */

    struct Node {
    Node* l = NULL; //r of the node
    Node* r = NULL; //l of the node
    int h = 0; //Height of the node
    int d = 0; //Data Part of the node
    };


    Node* getNode(int d){
      Node* node = new Node();
      node->d = d;
      node->l = NULL;
      node->r = NULL;
      node->h = 1;
      return (node);
    }

    int getH(Node* n) { //Getting the Height of Tree
    if (n == NULL)
        return 0;
    return n->h;
    }

    int getBlnc(Node* n){

    if (n == NULL)
        return 0;
    else {
        return getH(n->l) - getH(n->r);
    }
      }

    int havMaxValue(int j, int k){

    if (j > k)
        return j;
    return k;
    }

    /* AVL Rotatations */


    Node* rR(Node* temNode) //Right Rotation{

    Node* x = temNode->l;

    x->r = temNode;
    temNode->l = x->r;

    temNode->h = havMaxValue(getH(temNode->l), getH(temNode->r)) + 1;
    x->h = havMaxValue(getH(x->l), getH(x->r)) + 1;

    return x;
      }

    Node* lR(Node* TempNode) //LeftRotate
    {
    Node* tempNode2 = TempNode->r;
    Node* TemNode1 = tempNode2->l;

    tempNode2->l = TempNode;
    TempNode->r = TemNode1;

    TempNode->h = (havMaxValue(getH(TempNode->l), getH(TempNode->r)) + 1);
    tempNode2->h = (havMaxValue(getH(tempNode2->l), getH(tempNode2->r)) + 1);
    return tempNode2;
    }

    Node* inNode(Node* tempNode, int value) //Insert New Node
    {

    if (tempNode == NULL)
        return (getNode(value));

    if (value < tempNode->d)
        tempNode->l = inNode(tempNode->l, value);
    else if (value > tempNode->d)
        tempNode->r = inNode(tempNode->r, value);
    else
        return tempNode;

    tempNode->h = 1 + havMaxValue(getH(tempNode->l), getH(tempNode->r));

    int blnc = getBlnc(tempNode); //Balance Variable

    if (blnc > 1 && value < tempNode->l->d)
        return rR(tempNode);

    if (blnc < -1 && value > tempNode->r->d)
        return lR(tempNode);

    if (blnc > 1 && value > tempNode->l->d) {
        tempNode->l = lR(tempNode->l);
        return rR(tempNode);
    }

    if (blnc < -1 && value < tempNode->r->d) {
        tempNode->r = rR(tempNode->r);
        return lR(tempNode);
    }

    return tempNode;
    }

    /* Deletion */

    Node* nodeHavingMinVal(Node* temp) //Mininum Value Node
    {
    Node* tempNode = temp;
    while (tempNode->l != NULL)
        tempNode = tempNode->l;

    return tempNode;
    }

    Node* extractNode(Node* tempNode, int key) //DeleteNode
    {

    if (tempNode == NULL)
        return tempNode;

    if (key < tempNode->d)
        tempNode->l = extractNode(tempNode->l, key);

    else if (key > tempNode->d)
        tempNode->r = extractNode(tempNode->r, key);

    else {
        if ((tempNode->l == NULL) || (tempNode->r == NULL)) {
            Node* TempNode = tempNode->l ? tempNode->l : tempNode->r;

            if (TempNode == NULL) {
                TempNode = tempNode;
                tempNode = NULL;
            }
            else
                *tempNode = *TempNode;
        }
        else {
            Node* TempNode = nodeHavingMinVal(tempNode->r);
            tempNode->d = TempNode->d;
            tempNode->r = extractNode(tempNode->r, TempNode->d);
        }
    }

    if (tempNode == NULL)
        return tempNode;

    tempNode->h = 1 + max(getH(tempNode->l), getH(tempNode->r));

    int blnc = getBlnc(tempNode);

    if (blnc > 1 && getBlnc(tempNode->l) >= 0)
        return rR(tempNode);

    if (blnc > 1 && getBlnc(tempNode->l) < 0) {
        tempNode->l = lR(tempNode->l);
        return rR(tempNode);
    }

    if (blnc < -1 && getBlnc(tempNode->r) <= 0)
        return lR(tempNode);

    if (blnc < -1 && getBlnc(tempNode->r) > 0) {
        tempNode->r = rR(tempNode->r);
        return lR(tempNode);
    }

    return tempNode;
    }

    /* Graph Traversal */

    void POST(Node* node)
    {
    if (node == NULL)
        return;

    POST(node->l);
    POST(node->r);

    cout << node->d << " ";
    }

    void IN(Node* node)
    {
    if (node == NULL)
        return;

    IN(node->l);
    cout << node->d << " ";
    IN(node->r);
    }

    void PRE(Node* node)
    {
    if (node == NULL)
        return;

    cout << node->d << " ";

    PRE(node->l);
    PRE(node->r);
    }

    int main()
    {
    Node* root = NULL;
    char ch[5];
    int num;
    int i = 1;

    top:
       for (; i > 0;) {

        cin >> ch[0];

        if (ch[0] == 'A') {
            int num;
            cin >> num;
            root = inNode(root, num);
            goto top;
        }

        if (ch[0] == 'D') {
            int num;
            cin >> num;
            root = extractNode(root, num); //Delete Node
            if (root == NULL) {
                cout << "EMPTY";
                break;
            }
            goto top;
        }

        cin >> ch[1];
        if (ch[0] == 'I' and ch[1] == 'N') {
            IN(root);
            break;
        }

          cin >> ch[2];
          if (ch[0] == 'P' and ch[1] == 'R' and ch[2] == 'E') {
            PRE(root);
            break;
        }

        cin >> ch[3];
        if (ch[0] == 'P' and ch[1] == 'O' and ch[2] == 'S' and ch[3] == 'T') 
        {
            POST(root);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please refer to
[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and
[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)... Can you provide some details of what you have tried so far, where you think the error is. Also, what do you mean by input > 10? Is that the number of values in your space separated list? Also, can you explain in simple terms how "D13 D60 D76 D12 ... " becomes "4 6 9 12 13 ..." It may assist whoever tries to help you to work out the solution.

Comment: The problem is much more likely to be the structure than the size. Use small, systematic test cases, not large arbitrary ones.

Answer (score 2):

Your tree becomes invalid leading to `extractNode` invoking itself an unlimited number of times and causing a stack overflow. The easiest way to check where things are going awry is to write a function to traverse the entire tree and call it (with logging) after every modification. The last modification prior to the segfault is the problem.

You can confirm this by modifying your code like this:

```
Node* extractNode(Node* tempNode, int key, int depth) //DeleteNode
{
if (depth > 10)
    printf("depth=%d\n", depth);

if (tempNode == NULL)
    return tempNode;

if (key < tempNode->d)
    tempNode->l = extractNode(tempNode->l, key, depth + 1);

else if (key > tempNode->d)
    tempNode->r = extractNode(tempNode->r, key, depth + 1);

else {
    if ((tempNode->l == NULL) || (tempNode->r == NULL)) {
        Node* TempNode = tempNode->l ? tempNode->l : tempNode->r
```

And so on. Initially call it with a depth of zero. You'll see the depth rapidly increases and then the stack overflows.

> depth=11
>   depth=12
>   depth=13
>      << **many many lines** >>
>   depth=104724
>   depth=104725
>   depth=104726
>   depth=104727
>   depth=104728
>   depth=104729
>   depth=104730
>   depth=104731
>   depth=104732
>   depth=104733
>   depth=104734
>   Segmentation fault

Comment: Thanks for answer. I want to know please is this function is creating issue?

Comment: There's really no way I can tell because the code contains no comments so I can't tell what it's supposed to do. You really asked the wrong question. You should have asked, "How do I debug a segfault" and told us about your platform and preferred debugging tools.

Comment: You can also log `tempNode` on entry. That will allow you to tell whether it's stuck in a loop or whether you've created an absurd number of nodes. I'd suggest logging the tree after each modification to see where it goes off the rails. You can also add more logging to `extractNode` to make sure it's doing what you expect. If you have a debugger, use it. Personally, I prefer to add lots of logging to narrow down the problem.